# Icon image in croogo admin nav

Tags: croogo

I'm currently working with croogo for my back-end. How can I know which icons are available in admin nav in croogo?
and can I add my own element or view as a admin content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Croogo uses icons from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/.  At this time, both 1.5.x and 2.x is still using FontAwesome 3.0.2